# Mac Yosemite 10.10 Terminal Command Not found

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

I'm having a strange problem,

My path looks like this

```
$ echo $PATH

/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/php5/bin/

$ vim ~/.bash_profile

[ [-s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*

export MONGO_PATH=/usr/local/mongodb
export PATH=$PATH:$MONGO_PATH/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/composer
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/php5/bin/
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
alias composer='/usr/local/bin/composer/composer.phar'

if [ -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa ]; then
    ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa 2>/dev/null
fi
```

I still get command not found for most of my mongod elastic-search and other commands, please help.

Comment: Have you opened a new Terminal window or run `source ~/.bash_profile`?

Comment: I've used the same terminal window.

Comment: Changes to your bash profile don't take effect automatically. You'll need to open a new Terminal window or run `source ~/.bash_profile` for the changes to take effect.

Comment: I've restarted my Mac, also have tried it in new terminal. Still many command show strange command not found error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Ended up reinstalling my Mongo and ElasticSearch Engine and it works fine, some thing must have gone wrong while upgrading to Yosemite.